# Importing a interface in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I created a interface and tried to access it from an another class but i am getting the following error stating

> 'format'only refer's to a type but it is being used as a value here

my code looks like this

format.ts

```
export interface format{
 firstName : String;
}
```

appcomponent.ts

```
import {format} from "./directory"
export class AppComponent{
private Name = format[];
}
```

I am getting this error when I assign the interface to the private object `Name`.

Comment: First, do you mean `string` instead of `String`? Second, what is the syntax `format[]` supposed to mean? Do you mean `private Name: format[];`? You don't "assign" an interface to a private property (not "object"); you specify the interface as the **type**,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be

```
private Name: format[];
```

`=`  it means you assign array

`:` means that you describe variable, it will be array of type `format`.

Also you could do

```
private Name: format[] = [];
```

This means that you will have array of type `format` and when you will try to add anything to this array TypeScript will only accept object which implements this interface.